# Message Dialog Button language mismatch

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to display a message dialog in my application but the text of the displayed buttons are shown in some other language.

The platform is Windows8 with Qt5.5.1 and msvc2013_64 compiler

**Note:**

The problem occurs only when I copy all the dll and dependency to application directory for deployment. If I delete all the libraries from application directory and run it, it works fine.

This is the command I used to copy all the dll and dependency to app directory.

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\windeployqt.exe E:\Qt_Project\QMLTest2\release\QMLTest2.exe
```

Here is the QML code I used to create dialog.

```
          MessageDialog {
                    id:renameconfirmDialog
                    title: "Confirm Rename"
                    icon: StandardIcon.Question
                    text: "Are you sure you want to rename this preset?"
                    standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No
                    Component.onCompleted: visible = true

                    onYes: console.log("Rename")
                    onNo: console.log("Do not rename")
                }
```

The screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing button text in another language[1]]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

Actually the command

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\windeployqt.exe E:\Qt_Project\QMLTest2\release\QMLTest2.exe
```

Copying all the required dll to App directory, but the  `Qt5Core.dll` was creating the problem.

And I manually copy `Qt5Core.dll` from `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin` and replaced at app directory with the existing one which previously copied by above command.

But no idea why the above command not copying the proper dll, it might be  copying from some other folder.